# OpenGL - How to draw each nth triangle using glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: opengl, vbo, vao

I have a vertex buffer. There are situations when I don't want to render the whole mesh, but let's say each nth triangle of the mesh.
I am using VAOs and VBOs.

My data in the buffer is like this:

```
first triangle indx        seciond triangle indx
0 1 2   3 4 5   6 7 8    | 9 10 11   12 13 14   15 16 17 ...
```

What I want to do is - render first triangle, then skip second, then render 3d and so on.
Can it be done with adjusting `glVertexAttribPointer()` or are there some other `gl` methods that can manipulate the data like that, or I have to create a new buffer with skipped triangles ?

Comment: I guess creating a new buffer is the only solution here. I am not sure though.

Comment: How about solving this at the glDrawArrays level?

Comment: As far as I know glDrawArrays takes the number of vertices to be drawn. I can't tell it to draw each nth vertex/triangle can I ?

Comment: .. I guess you could just have shader discard all fragments of the non-wanted triangles ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why would you want to draw each n-th triangle, and I cannot imagine a situation in which you would want to do that.

...but supposing you do have a legitimate reason to do that...

I would say you can't, because `glVertexAttribPointer` is used to set the layout for the data at the *vertex* level, not the *triangle* level. In fact, OpenGL has no idea of how are you going to use the vertices inside the vertex buffer until you make a draw call.

I suppose you were thinking about playing with the `stride` parameter, but once again, `glVertexAttribPointer` works at the vertex level, so the most you can do is make triangles out of each n-th vertex, which is not what you want.

Short of creating a new vertex buffer, you can handle this when making the draw call. `glDrawArrays` takes the amount of triangles you want to draw and the offset from which you want to draw them, so you would have to do something like

```
for (int k = 0; k < totalTriangleCount; k += n)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, k * 3, 3);
```

You might be tempted to think that this is a performance killer, but it's most likely not. You will most likely not be issuing an OpenGL flush on each `glDrawArrays` call, so I wouldn't say performance would drop noticeably. At least compared with creating and uploading a new vertex buffer each frame.

Now, the real question is "why would you want to do such a thing?", but we may never know...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
Now to answer your question - When I have extremely large mesh, If I want to update it (rotate, translate...) I gain a significant improvement in the framerates when I redraw it with less triangles than the original. And when I stop updating it - I render it with all the triangles.

Comment: @Geto then you could just reorder the triangles sot he first third is the third you want to draw

Answer (score 3):

you can step away from `glDrawArrays` and instead use `glDrawElements` and use a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER​` buffer that hold the indexes of the vertexes you want to draw

the element buffer would then contain `{0,1,2,9,10,11,...}` and so on.

In you comments I see that you want this to draw a "light" object for quick updates, you can add all other triangles after the first third and draw all triangles that way